# Script that checks I'm deploying to the correct kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a script that deploys my application to my kubernetes cluster. However, if my current kubectl context is pointing at the wrong cluster, I can easily end up deploying my application to a cluster that I did not intend to deploy it to. What is a good way to check (from inside a script) that I'm deploying to the right cluster?

I don't really want to hardcode a specific kubectl context name, since different developers on my team have different conventions for how to name their kubectl contexts.

Instead, I'd like something more like `if $(kubectl get cluster-name) != "expected-clsuter-name" then error`.

Comment: It's not what you asked, but this ps1 script can help you keep your context in mind... https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(kubectl config current-context) != "your-cluster-name" ]
then
    echo "Do some error!!!"
    return
fi

echo "Do some kubectl command"
```

Above script get the cluster name and match with `your-desired-cluster` name. If mismatch then give error. Otherwise run desire kubectl command.

Comment: I don't really want to hardcode a specific kubectl context name, since different developers on my team have different conventions for how to name their kubectl contexts.

Comment: Then how can you define desire cluster name. pass variable or something? or interactive CLI?

Answer (score 1):

For each cluster run `kubectl cluster-info` once to see [what the IP/host for master is](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3290) - that should be stable for the cluster and not vary with the name in the kubectl context (which developers might be setting differently). Then capture that in the script with `export MASTERA=<HOST/IP>` where that's the master for cluster A. Then the script can do:

`kubectl cluster-info | grep -q $MASTERA && echo 'on MASTERA'`

Or [use an if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931244/checking-if-output-of-a-command-contains-a-certain-string-in-a-shell-script/31195882):

```
if kubectl cluster-info | grep -q $MASTERA; then
   echo 'on $MASTERA'
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Hmm on GKE there are no hostnames for the master nodes, and the IP addresses aren't very meaningful or easy to remember

Comment: Yeah presumably this is why you're trying a different approach under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842487/stop-kubectl-from-printing-pod-curl-deleted-at-end as that seems to give you a more meaningful name

Comment: With gke another way would be to use `kubectl get nodes` as the cluster name gets used in the node names but that doesn't hold for other clouds.